# How do gasless fee transactions work on the polygon(matic) network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft

I looked into the opensea implements for polygon network. Users don't need to pay any fee on network as far as I know, but when I created my own smart contract and called a function (on remix) metamask asked to pay a gas fee on MATIC to call smart contract.

How can we create search system where use don't have to pay gas fee (as opensea has now)? I assumed that network itself didn't required gas fee but I guess it's not true.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we can create search system where use don't have to pay gas fee

User signs messages in their MetaMask wallet. This message is sent off-chain to an Opensea server. The Opensea server performs a transaction and pays the fee on behalf of the user. The smart contract is programmed to handle these messages sent on behalf of somebody else. In the end, someone always pays the gas.

Alternative, a transaction does not involve blockchain at all, which might I believe is the bid on OpenSea auction bids. It does not happen on a blockchain, but is centralised.

Comment: Understood but how to achieve this ? I mean how can I create same system. What terms or concept should I google to learn about it and create same stuff.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading OpenSea smart contracts and spend some weeks studying them. When you understand exactly how they work then have an idea how to create a similar system.

Comment: Does it work like L2 or meta transaction?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: yea can't i use meta transcation to achieve same ?

Comment: @Arrow This link might be helpful https://docs.opensea.io/docs/polygon-basic-integration